# How to move cursor to the next row in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a Windows Form that contains 2 datagridviews and a button between them to transfer the data. I cannot figure out how should i move the cursor of selected row to the next row after the button has successfully transfer the data.

Comment: Imho I wouldn't move the cursor but highlight new newly added items. Moving the cursor without any information to the user is highly anoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell =
        dataGridView1
        .Rows[Math.Min(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)]
        .Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
```

Comment: This is selecting the cell not the cursor. I would prefer this option than moving the cursor imho.

Comment: @PoweRoy, I've assumed that "move the cursor" is some kind of *metaphor* of "select next row".

Answer (score -1):

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    int col = grdIdeal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int row = grdIdeal.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int nRows = grdIdeal.Rows.Count - 1;
    int nCol = grdIdeal.Columns.Count - 1;

    if (nCol == col && nRows == row)
        grdIdeal.CurrentCell = grdIdeal[0, 0];
    else if (nRows == row)
        grdIdeal.CurrentCell = grdIdeal[col + 1, 0];
    else
        grdIdeal.CurrentCell = grdIdeal[col, row + 1];
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, welcome to Stack Overflow. When you know how to answer a question, it's often good to provide some explanation of what you've done and why.