# move index in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

i am using that: `Datagridview.DataSource= Table`
now in variable "Table" have these:

```
PersonID|LName
-----------
1|TEST1
----------
2|TEST2
----------
3|TEST3
```

now i wanna to make a button that move from the row is current to the next Row
as example

from that status

[image]

to

[image]

If you not understand from the first row to second row
just move the pointer to next line

edit:
look in the picture the ">" <==> pointer how i can move it to next/prev line/row

**found Answer here :
[How to move cursor to the next row in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209056/how-to-move-cursor-to-the-next-row-in-datagridview)**

Comment: i didn't mean to dupli just move the pointer that point right now on the line 1 to point the line 2

edit: that navigating to next row is just selected the next row

Comment: i found the answer here in SOF

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209056/how-to-move-cursor-to-the-next-row-in-datagridview

Comment: so in the end it *was* a duplicate, just not the one I referred to first :-) - but I find your version much nicer in regards to format and understandability +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the CurrentRow Property to make the triangle move. However, the CurrentRow is readonly. According to [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will have to set the [CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property to a cell in the next line to make it change:

> To change the current row, you must set the [CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to a cell in the desired row.

Comment: ty but i still dont know how do it

i tried that:
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[2].DataGridView.CurrentCell;

Comment: @AsafShazar did you succeed? I don't have a dev-environment around but I'd gladly add your code to the answer.

Comment: yes i found the success glad of your topic you gave me
i search in stackoverflow How change row with  CurrentCell and found it in 1-3 min after

Answer (score 1):

You can get from your button the current selected line :

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView.SelectedIndex.ToString());
```

You can then set this one +1 for the next row.

```
DataGridView.Rows(index+1).Selected = True
```

Comment: there no function that property "SelectedIndex"

Comment: If none is selected, just do a IF and check if it return something <0. If yes, set the Index to zero.

Comment: wait i just now check it , that select the next row, i didnt mean that just wanna move next the pointer, sorry for misunderstand me i mean not to select , just move the pointer